# How to get the class name of a polymorph C++ Object using WIN32 Debug Info API?

Tags: c++, winapi, reflection, debug-information

**The win32 debugger shows the class name in question in the inspector window that means the information must be available, it's only in question wether the microsoft developers made the function public.**

**For Debug/Diagnostic/development purpose** i wanna write a function to get the instanciated class name of a c++ object as an output and as an input the pointer to the base class.

For example:

```
const char* GetNameOfInstanciatedClassByBaseClassPtr(class B* pBaseClassOrInstanciatedClass);

class B { public: virtual void Init (){
  assert(StringIsEqual(GetNameOfInstanciatedClassByBaseClassPtr(this), "C")); } };
class C : B {} c; c.Init();
```

So please provide a solution for implementation of function **GetNameOfInstanciatedClassByBaseClassPtr**.

So question is: Whats the required lib/header/function ? I guess a API for the win32 Debug info would help?

Writing virtual functions which return strings or type_info is not an acceptable solution in my situation.

As i said before: this is for diagnostic/debug/development purpose only, **NOT for production code** so please avoid discussions about clean code purposes. I could also collect the information manually but since it's about 260 classes i might be faster this way. ;)

EDIT: In the first version of the question i had the function 'GetNameOfInstanciatedClassByBaseClassPtr' called in the constructor of the base class but i observed the information is not yet available in the constructor time. So i put it to an Init method which is always called. In this method the debugger shows the name of the instanciated class so if i put call to the function GetNameOfInstanciatedClassByBaseClassPtr into my init method the information can be obtained. Same seems to be true for the rtti-typeinfo.

EDIT2:
As mentioned it may not work for void*, you may need a class B*. However, this can be easily tested. Note some things may be compiler specific. So i adapted the question again.

**So the answer i took from the comments is to use either**

- **Runtime Type Information (rtti) (through native c++)** [1]
- **Microsoft Debug Interface Access SDK (through COM)** [2]

[1] You need to enable this feature in your compiler settings for file or project.

[2] That is the more complex solution.

Comment: *"The win32 debugger shows the class name in question in the inspector window"* from a `void*` or from a `B*`?

Comment: debugger use pdb file. take pointer to virtual table. look which symbol name at this address. parse name. etc. all this very not simply

Comment: This information gets emitted by the linker into a program database (PDB) file. You can use the [Debug Interface Access SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk) to query the information from there.

Comment: @Jarod42: Good point, it was definitely not the void*, it wsa a class*. Also i think the typeinfo may work in my case, of course not inside the constructor, at a point where the child class is not initialized...

Comment: @IInspectable: Very valueable, thank you. That was my first approach after i reputed found, that typeinfo does not work. but as i said it could not work in the base class constructor for the child class in c++ i think. i think it can be done with the debug interface access sdk and also the typeinfo at least inside a function called after the object has been completely constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A {
    virtual void printName(){
        std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << "\n";
    }
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
struct C : A{};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.printName();
    A a;
    a.printName();
}
```

However, the name is implementation defined. [Possible output is](https://godbolt.org/z/Mor3hEs6T):

```
1C
1A
```

And you cannot get the `typeid` of the dynamic type of the object from a `void*`. See this somewhat related question: [How to get the typeid of a void* pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572191/how-to-get-the-typeid-of-a-void-pointer)

Also (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> If `typeid` is used on an object under construction or destruction (in a destructor or in a constructor, including constructor's initializer list or default member initializers), then the std::type_info object referred to by this typeid represents the class that is being constructed or destroyed even if it is not the most-derived class.

That is, you cannot use `typeid` to infer the dynamic type in the constructor (or destructor). The only way I am aware of to get your hands on the dynamic type in a constructor or destructor is a `dynamic_cast`, but then you need to know the type beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it just returned the name of the base class. I enabled the rtti compiler option, to make it work like this. is there an extra option in win32 to make it return the child class name?

Comment: @seebee not sure what you mean. `1C` is the name of `C`

Comment: Ye but you said depending of the implementation (of the compiler?!) it may also return 1A (name of A). In my case this happened but this doesn't solve the problem since i need the name of the "sealed" / "instanciated" class "C" / "1C". I'm asking wether microsoft implemented a compiler switch to control this behaviour (Return 1A or 1C)

Comment: @seebee the names are implementation defined per class. Ie output could also be `CCC  AAA`. Different classes have different names

Comment: of course it is not in question the resulting class name will represent the actual identifier used in the code. the question is, wether the information for the child class is available in the base class constructor. and this seems to fail, for rtti and for debug info. so also for a class ChildClass the result will be "BaseClass" if you call the GetTypeInfo in the constructor of class BaseClass. That is different to c# i think.

Comment: @seebee in constructor ans destructors the dynamic  type does not matter. In constr/dest the type is always die type your currenlty constructir / destructing

Comment: @seebee see edit. It isnt possible in the constructor

Comment: yes exactly. thats the point it isnt possible in the *baseclass* contructor. actually i was a bit out of focus with c++ since i did c# a very long time. i remember better now how the memory model works in c++ and now it seems obvious to me that it does not work in the base ctor.