# Is memory allocation for class and struct have the same behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

Is memory allocation for class (when initializing an object) is the same as struct? I know that when we initialize struct,

```
struct example {
    int a;
    double b; 
    int c;
}
```

the memory allocated will be = (0-4) int, (8-16) double, (16-20) int. (If I am not mistaken)

What if we want to initialize

```
class Example {
private:
    int a;
    double b;
    int c;
public:
    Example();
}

Example object();
```

?

What's the memory allocation behavior when the object is initialized? Is it the same as struct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Literally the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that in a `struct`, member-variables/methods listed in the first section of the declaration (above any `public:/protected:/private:` lines) are treated as `public`, whereas in a `class` they are treated as `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Ask `sizeof`. It is always correct. In this simple case, the class is guaranteed to have no hidden members; in general that isn't true.

The rule isn't about `class` vs `struct`; the only difference is the default in `struct` is public members but `class` is private members. The rule is about when you use expensive things. When you add `virtual` in, the sizes of things start to change. When you add `virtual` inheritance, things get a lot bigger.

You can only use RTTI on a class that has a virtual member. See [How to get the typeid of a void* pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572191/how-to-get-the-typeid-of-a-void-pointer) for details.

You have asked a further question; whether you can just add up the sizes of the members. The answer is a definite "No". You can't do that. On my platform, that struct may well take up, 24 bytes due to alignment (the `double` wants to be 8 byte aligned).

Comment: Ah, yes. I just tried the sizeof, it turns out both the object from the class and struct are the same (in this case). However, I haven't tried to add a function member, yet, to the class. Might try to do so.

For the total memory allocated, it is 24 bytes (same as yours). From my understanding, the int a will be allocated (0-4), empty (4-8), double (8-16), int (16-20), and empty again (20-24). Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: @MariaKhelli: Adding a non-virtual member function will make no difference.